# jointjs: svg text is replaced by blank on drop to paper

Tags: javascript, svg, backbone.js, jointjs

In stencils we have png, on drop to paper we replace cell[png] with svg.

cell - represents png
vectorString - markup of png

```
        var currentSvg = new joint.shapes.basic.pwmeter({
            position: { x: bbox.x, y: bbox.y },
            size: { height: cell.attributes.minHeight, width: cell.attributes.minWidth },
            minWidth: cell.attributes.minWidth,
            minHeight: cell.attributes.minHeight,
            markup: vectorString,
            type: cell.attributes.type,
            fileName: cell.attributes.fileName,
            isInteractive: true,
            elementClassName: cell.attributes.elementClassName,
            isAnimatedDevice: cell.attributes.isAnimatedDevice,
            attrs: {
            '.myClass': {
                  fill: '#ffffff',
                stroke: '#000000'
                      }
               }
            });

    currentSvg.addTo(Rappid.graph);
```

---

we are making pwmeter by extending Image
        joint.shapes.basic.pwmeter = joint.shapes.basic.Image.extend({
            type: 'basic.pwmeter',
            initialize: function () {
                return joint.shapes.basic.Image.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });

We drop png from stencils to paper, and get svg markup for corresponding png,
we call currentSvg.addTo(Rappid.graph), during execution of this, all text in meter [svg] are replaced by blank.

our text - 0

auto generated code replaces my text, we are not able to figure out why this is happening

> -

above is the generated text
We are new to jointjs, we think we are doing something wrong during extending.

Answer (score 2):

I can see there is a `markup` in you settings. Make sure there is a text 'placeholder' in the markup.

in this example attr `text` is tied with the `<text/>` element

```
new joint.shapes.basic.pwmeter({
    markup: '<g><image/><text/></g>',
    attrs: {
        text: { text: '48x48' },
        image: { 'xlink:href': 'http://placehold.it/48x48', width: 48, height: 48 }
    },
    size: { width : 50, height: 50 },
    position: { x:200, y: 50},
}).addTo(graph)
```

but in here, attr `text` has no matching element in the markup, therefore it won't be rendered.

```
new joint.shapes.basic.pwmeter({
    markup: '<g><image/></g>',
    attrs: {
       text: { text: '90x90' },
       image: { 'xlink:href': 'http://placehold.it/90x90', width: 90, height: 90 }
    },
    size: { width : 90, height: 90 },
    position: { x:50, y: 50},
}).addTo(graph)
```

more information about `attr` property could be found here http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#joint.dia.Element.presentation